# Extract video url from youtube url

Tags: android, url, youtube, exoplayer

I want to extract video url from youtube url.
Because I want to use that url to play video in exoplayer or any other video player.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the code you're using - see **[ask]**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Youtube player`?Also, don't use `Exoplayer`. It is very large library.(About 4 MB+)

1. Add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.0.1'
```

2. The `xml` code

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:autoPlay="true" />
```

3. The java code(To load the video)

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = getVideoId();
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

4. And the get video id method

```
String getVideoId(String videoUrl){
    if(url.contains("watch?v=") return url.split("watch?v=");
    return videoId;
}
```

Comment: Bro there are many reasons why I am not using YouTube player 1. YouTube player do not give as customization that exoplayer gives   2.  For Using YouTube player it is mandatory to have YouTube installed in device 3.  YouTube also uses ExoPlayer internally so we can know the quality of exoplayer